# How do I change the nameservers for my AWS Route53 Registered Domain using boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-route53

I'm unable to use the AWS [boto API](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to change name servers for my AWS [Route53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) Registered Domain. In the following Python code, I get

```
boto.exception.JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{u'Message': u'Expected null', u'__type': u'SerializationException'}
```

even though I'm using the API [as documented](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/route53domains.html#boto.route53.domains.layer1.Route53DomainsConnection.update_domain_nameservers), passing a list of strings such as

```
['ns-705.awsdns-21.net', 'ns-1401.awsdns-24.org', 'ns-1107.awsdns-11.co.uk', 'ns-242.awsdns-75.com']
```

as the second argument.

How can I change nameservers from Python?

---

```
def createhz(domain=None, verbose=False):
    """Create a Hosted Zone for the specified domain and update nameservers for Route53 Registered Domain"""
    r53 = boto.route53.connection.Route53Connection()
    if r53.get_hosted_zone_by_name(domain + '.'):
        print('WARNING: Hosted Zone for {} already exists.'.format(domain))
        hz = r53.get_zone(domain + '.')
    else:
        if verbose:
            print('Creating Hosted Zone for {}.'.format(domain))
        hz = r53.create_zone(domain + '.')

    nameservers = hz.get_nameservers()
    if verbose:
        print('Hosted Zone has nameservers:')
        for ns in nameservers:
            print('  {}'.format(ns))

    registered_domains = boto.route53.domains.layer1.Route53DomainsConnection()

    try:
        registered_domains.get_domain_detail(domain)
        if verbose:
            print('Updating nameservers for Route53 Registered Domain.'.format(domain))
        # THE FOLLOWING LINE FAILS
        registered_domains.update_domain_nameservers(domain, nameservers)
    except Exception as e:
        if e.message == 'Domain not found.':
            print('WARNING: No Route53 Registered Domain for {}.'.format(domain))
            print('Set the nameservers at your domain registrar to:.'.format(domain))
            for ns in nameservers:
                print('  {}'.format(ns))
        else:
            raise e

    return
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 362, in <module>
    manager.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 412, in run
    result = self.handle(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 383, in handle
    res = handle(*args, **config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_script/commands.py", line 216, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "manage.py", line 336, in createhz
    raise e
boto.exception.JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{u'Message': u'Expected null', u'__type': u'SerializationException'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The support for the Route53 domain functionality is pretty new in boto and not very well documented.  By looking at the service API I see that the `update_domain_servers` method expects the `nameservers` parameter to be a list of dictionaries of the form:

```
[{"Name": "ns1.example.com"}, {"Name": "ns2.example.com"}]
```

There is also an optional key called `GlueIps`.  It doesn't sound like that would be necessary for your case but you can find more information [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/api-update-domain-name-servers.html)

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this myself so here's what I did (based on your example above).. btw, this is based on Boto v2, fyi:

The below line:

```
nameservers = hz.get_nameservers()
```

Actually returns a list of NSs, such as:

```
[u'ns-1069.awsdns-05.org.', u'ns-1755.awsdns-27.co.uk.', u'ns-399.awsdns-49.com.', u'ns-816.awsdns-38.net.']
```

BUT, when you want to run `registered_domains.update_domain_nameservers(domain, nameservers)` you have to pass in a JSON list with key values of "Name", such as:

```
[{u'Name': u'ns-1515.awsdns-61.org'}, {u'Name': u'ns-576.awsdns-08.net'}]
```

To convert, you can do something like this

```
ns = [dict(Name=pn) for pn in nameservers]
```

And then you can update the NS records:

```
registered_domains.update_domain_nameservers(domain, ns)
```

Hope this helps!

Sorry I am posting from 2 accounts - fixed!